# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'filters'

Tags: javascript, filter, blend

This is my instructor's demo, he made a banner(like a slide) with 3 pictures will change repeatedly.
When i applied this code to my project, it comes out an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'filters' .

I ask him and he said the 'filters' method is used for IE browser, if i want to use it in chrome or firefox, i must find an alternative method.

I've searched google but still not found the answer. Please can someone tell me how to fix this error. Thank you so much.

JS code:

```
var switchImage = 0;
var imageArray = ['image1','image2','image3'];
function blend() {
    for (var i =0; i <imageArray.length; i++) {
        if (i != switchImage) {
            document.getElementById(imageArray[i]).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(imageArray[i]).filters("blendTrans").apply();
            document.getElementById(imageArray[i]).filters("blendTrans").play();
        }
    }
}
function reBlend() {
    switchImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    document.getElementById(imageArray[switchImage]).style.visibility = "visible" ;
    for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
        if (i != switchImage) {
            document.getElementById(imageArray[switchImage]).style.zIndex -= 4;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(imageArray[switchImage]).style.zIndex += 4;
        }
    }
    blend();
}
```

Image code:

```
<IMG ID ="image1" SRC ="images/banner1.png" ONFILTERCHANGE ="reBlend()"
             style="position:absolute; 
                         filter:blendTrans(duration=3); z-index: 3"/>
<IMG ID ="image2" SRC ="images/banner2.jpg" ONFILTERCHANGE ="reBlend()"
             style="position:absolute; 
                         filter:blendTrans(duration=3); z-index: 2"/>
<IMG ID ="image3" SRC ="images/banner3.jpg" ONFILTERCHANGE ="reBlend()"
             style="position:absolute;
                         filter:blendTrans(duration=3); z-index: 1"/>
```

Comment: I'm your instructor. Keep searching!

Comment: sr but i'm not from Irael...

Comment: I'm joking. Good luck!

Comment: `.filters` is not a method, it should be used with `[]` like `element.filters["alpha"]`